# Performance considerations with db.BlobProperty()

Tags: google-app-engine

In my app, I'd like to have an entity defined like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    title           = db.StringProperty()
    myBlob          = db.BlobProperty()
```

Say this blob holds around 1 megabyte.  Will this slow down any queries I make on the MyModel type?  Is it fetching the entire 1mb per entity, or just references until I actually try to access the blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minute you retrieve the entity, the blob is loaded from the datastore unless you do a projection query.

You have a few options to avoid loading the BlobProperty until you need it.

1. do a projection query and then only fetch the full entity when you need it.
2. stick the BlobProperty in a Child entity (make the top level one the ancestor) and only fetch the property with a get, when you need it.
3. Don't use a BlobProperty but stick it in GCS (Google CLoud Storage) and serve it from there.

The last has the benefit that if you do no processing on the blob your appengine instance doesn't need to get involved with serving it (depending on what your requirements are of course)

Comment: By projection query, I'm assuming you mean setting keys_only=true?  Also I was looking at using GCS but there's an additional cost associated with it.  Why would I use it if I have access to BlobProperty and BlobStore with App Engine?

Comment: BlobStore is being deprecated.  GCS serves the content directly (also allows things like image manipulation on retrieval like BlobStore (GCS is replacing Blobstore).  And finally project queries are not like Keys only queries.   Hvae a read - you can sleect which properties you return.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection .  Oh and if you are close to 1MB are you ever likely to go over 1MB?  The GCS is it.